# erlang:system_time/1 undefined function

Tags: time, erlang

When I call the function `erlang:system_time(seconds).` The shell throws an undefined function error. I have followed the documentation for the function [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_time-1). I tried this on OTP 17.

Comment: on which version of OTP?

Comment: I updated my question @Atomic_alarm

Comment: this feature was added to 18.0. You can download documentation for OTP 17 as HTML file and see: https://www.erlang.org/downloads/17.4

Comment: We should probably either close or answer this question :)

Comment: ok, here I am a year after this question was raised, using OTP 19, and: calls to timestamp(), erlang:timestamp(), system_time() all cause ** exception error: undefined function erlang:timestamp/0'"